# How to access a variable inside a function without the construction of a global?

Tags: php, declare

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);
function tick_handler()
{
print($GLOBALS['a']);
}
register_tick_function('tick_handler');


function test()
{
$a = 1;//This not print
$a = 2;//This not print
$a = 3;//This not print
$a = 4;//This not print
}
test();
$a = 1;//This print
$a = 2;//This print
$a = 3;//This print
$a = 4;//This print
?>
```

How print //This not print  ,but without global $a ?

And without

```
function test()
{
$GLOBALS['a'] = 1;//This not print
$GLOBALS['a'] = 2;//This not print
$GLOBALS['a'] = 3;//This not print
$GLOBALS['a'] = 4;//This not print
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do what you want here. But **why?** There has to be a better way to do what you want to do. Personally I have *never* seen `register_tick_function` in real-world code.

Comment: On duty, I have to work with a few CMS, until you find exactly where formed HTML-code is a couple of hours, especially when the classes and functions are called. Therefore it is necessary to code to work with scripts engines. I want to look at what exactly a file, string, variable conceived piece of HTML-code

Comment: This rather sounds like you are looking for XDebug.

Comment: For example, in Joomla to change the label prescribed bottom of the page bottom of page for this
1) You must download hosting dump script
2) Find a piece of html script code that is next to
3) To investigate the behavior of functions
4) Find a place html code education
It takes a couple of hours
I just find with the help of $globals and register_tick_function

Comment: Yeah, use XDebug: 
http://www.xdebug.org/

Comment: Big Thanks ,but xdebug in hostmonster.com disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do but

> For example, in Joomla to change the label prescribed bottom of the page bottom of page for this 1) You must download hosting dump script 2) Find a piece of html script code that is next to 3) To investigate the behavior of functions 4) Find a place html code education It takes a couple of hours I just find with the help of $globals and register_tick_function

sounds like [you-are-doing-it-wrong](/questions/tagged/you-are-doing-it-wrong).

If you need to debug your application and/or need to see which functions and methods got called in what order and with what parameters, then use a proper debugger:

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494288/good-free-php-debugger

> Big Thanks, but xdebug in hostmonster.com disabled

You do **not** want to debug your production site. If you need to add more features or apply changes, do so on your development server first. Make sure it works, then deploy the changes to your production site. So either put XDebug on your local machine or into a VM or anything like that. Or get a new hoster for your development environment. In any case, put it where development and debugging wont disrupt production.